# Django custom app config

Tags: python, django

I would like to run code that will be executed only once in django app.

my structure:

```
company
  project
    common
      project_config.py
  __init__.py
```

**__init__.py**:

```
default_app_config = "company.project.common.ProjectConfig"
```

**settings.py**:

```
..
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  "company.project"
)
..
```

**ProjectConfig.py**:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ProjectConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "company.project"

    def ready(self):
        do_something()
```

I don't see that the method of ready() in my config is being called.

What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do here, but don't you need to call the "ready" function somewhere? Have you tried starting the Django shell, importing ProjectConfig, and running ready to see if it produces the desired result?

Comment: According to the documentation ready should be called by Django

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#for-application-users), you dont need `_init_.py` file, just point INSTALLED_APPS up to `AppConfig` subclass:

Try this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'company.project.common.ProjectConfig',
)
```